# How to move elements in the navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap template. I want to make the template elements rtl
so I have set the site title to  rtl in the navbar, but the button also in the navbar gets rtl.

My code shows the site title on the left and the buttons on the right
But I don't want this. I want the buttons to be on the left side
and the title of the site on the right. Actually I want the buttons to be ltr. For example see the below schema:

```
<signup button> <login button>                               <title>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

        <head>

          <title> Edenthought </title>


          <meta charset="utf-8" />

          <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>


          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/5/morph/bootstrap.min.css">


          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">


          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


        </head>


        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light justify-content-center">

            <a class="navbar-brand main-heading"> 
                    
              &nbsp; Edenthought 
            
            </a>
        
        
            <button
              class="navbar-toggler"
              type="button"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
              aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        
            </button>
        
        
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        
                
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        
        
                  &nbsp;     &nbsp;     &nbsp; 
        
        
                  <li class="nav-item">
              
                    <a class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" type="button"  href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
        
                  </li>
        
        
                  &nbsp;     &nbsp;     &nbsp; 
                  
        
                  <li class="nav-item">
        
                    <a class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" type="button"  href="{% url 'my-login' %}">Login</a>
        
                  </li>
        
        
                  &nbsp;     &nbsp;     &nbsp; 
                  
        
                </ul>
              
                
              </div>
        
        
        </nav>



        <body>
      
            <br>
            <br>
      
            <div class="text-center">
      
            <h2> Edenthought.... A home for your thoughts. </h2>
      
              <br>
                
            
              <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button"  href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
      
            
            </div>
      
      
          </body>



        <script src=""></script>


        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"

        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"

        crossorigin="anonymous">

        </script>

        <script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>


    </html>
```

Comment: Protip: Don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not their purpose. Bootstrap provides plenty of [spacing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/) to do that properly.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: Explain what more? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use br tags. use the margin class of Bootstrap instead. In this modified version, I moved the buttons () to the left side (me-auto class) and the site title () to the right side. And for the mobile view, I changed the order.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> Edenthought </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/5/morph/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light justify-content-center">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" type="button" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" type="button" href="{% url 'my-login' %}">Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <a class="navbar-brand main-heading ms-auto order-1 order-lg-0">Edenthought</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </nav>

    <div class="text-center mt-4">
      <h2> Edenthought.... A home for your thoughts. </h2>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
    </div>

    <script src=""></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is correct, but there is a problem, there is not any space between the login and register button

Comment: Use "me-2" in the button class.